# Is a root of $x^4+x^2+1$ constructible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, factoring

My problem is as the title, what is that mean that the root of this is constructible or not? Here is what I try:

Let $ u = x^2$ transform the polynomial to $u^2+u+1$ then we know the roots will be $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3i}{2}$, so we need to check if $Q[1,\sqrt3i]$ is constructible ?

Comment: You can make a unit length equilateral triangle with one vertex at the origin and a side along the negative real axis, and then bisect the side coming from the origin into the upper left plane. That point will be at $-\frac{1}{2}+\mathrm i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.

Comment: @FlybyNight But, what is that mean that if it's contructible or not?

Comment: It means it is constructible with a compass and straightedge. This is not surprising, as the quartic in the original question is clearly reducible to two quadratics.There are reducible quartics which have at least one non-constructible root. One obvious example is $x^4-2x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^4+x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$
All root of quadratic equation is constructible.

Answer (score 3):

$$ x^4 + x^2 + 1 = \left( x^2 + x + 1\right)  \left( x^2 - x + 1\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously so, because all the exponents are multiples of 2, and so this is a quadratic equation in terms of $x^2$. $x$ can be derived by a finite number of arithmetic operations and square root extrations involving only rational numbers, so it is constructible.

Its resolvent cubic is $8z^3+12z^2+16z=0$, which clearly has the rational root $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x^4 + x^2 + 1 = \left( x^2 + 1\right) ^2  -x^2= (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1) $$

Two binomials with discriminant negative, each one is constructible.

Further on, factoring for complex roots we have the 4 roots constructed ( 4 small red dots) and shown in the complex plane with four out of six vertices of a regular hexagon of unit radius:

$$ x= \frac{\pm1\pm\sqrt3 i}{2}$$

[image]